# Tkinter Frame Color

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to modify a Tkinter Frame using ttk.Style to customize the color of a Tkinter Frame and have even tried a ttk.Frame to use HEX colors for a frame background but can't get it to work, here is my code:

```
self.style.theme_create( "rePOS", parent="alt", settings={
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {"padding": [20, 10], "background": self.tabColor },
                "map":       {"background": [("selected", self.tabSelectedColor)]},

            },
            "TFrame": {
                "background": "#77cd00"
            }
        }
    )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another question similar, it seems using this works:

```
color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (119, 205, 000)'
```

Using this with an RGB color works and setting it so the color variable will produce the background.